# Display none being added since removing jquery ui script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to JavaScript, this is one of my first scripts.

basically i am trying to create a script that turns a grid based news list into a list based news list. i got it all working great when had both

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

but i have removed the ui script as i dont really need it (i think)

and now my script isn't functioning properly. My Script is

```
//Javascript Start 

//SETTINGS
var settings = {
    //Header Slider Settings
    listBtn: 'input.toggle',
    listItem: '.wrapper ul',
    listStyleOne: 'listNews-tiled',
    listStyleTwo: 'listNews-list',
    fadeSpeed: 300
}

function NewsListSwitcher() {
    $(settings.listBtn).click(function () {
        //If News List has a certian class
        if ($(settings.listItem).hasClass(settings.listStyleOne)) {
            //Fade Out and remove Class
            $(settings.listItem).fadeOut(settings.fadeSpeed,
                function () {
                    $(settings.listItem).removeClass(settings.listStyleOne);
                }
            );
            //Add Class and Fade In
            $(settings.listItem).addClass(settings.listStyleTwo,
                function () {
                    $(settings.listItem).fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                }
            );
            //Change background Position Of List Button
            $(settings.listBtn).css("background-position","bottom");
        }
        else {
            //Fade Out and remove class
            $(settings.listItem).fadeOut(settings.fadeSpeed,
                function () {
                    $(settings.listItem).removeClass(settings.listStyleTwo);
                }
            );
            //Add Class and Fade In
            $(settings.listItem).addClass(settings.listStyleOne,
                function () {
                    $(settings.listItem).fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
                }
            );
            //Change background Position Of List Button
            $(settings.listBtn).css("background-position","top");
        }
    });
}
//Javascript End
```

my html is just a basic list

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="submit" class="toggle" value="">
    <hr />
    <ul class="listNews-tiled">
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

what is happening is when i click my icon, the script removed listNews-tiled class and adds listNews-List class, but it also adds display block: none; which i dont want.

If you could help that would be amazing.

Link to Preview
http://www.psykestudios.co.uk/News%20List-Grid%20selector/

Comment: So which one is it? It adds "display: block" or "display: none" and which one of those you don't *want*? Plus, why don't you want that? I mean what's wrong with that?

Comment: if you see this 

http://www.psykestudios.co.uk/News%20List-Grid%20selector/

example you can see what i mean by display none and not wanting it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) doesn't support finish callback (as opposed to `fadeIn` or `fadeOut`) like you apparently think. Meaning code like: `$(body).addClass('example', function() {...})` won't run the function once the class is added. The class is added instantly. Documentation states that function may be passed to `addClass` but it is expected of it to return string that will be added as class name.

**As a fix**, replace parts when you pass function to addClass with something like:

```
$(settings.listItem).addClass(settings.listStyleTwo).fadeIn(settings.fadeSpeed);
```

Edit:
Hah, there was much more to this question than I originally thougth.

I checked, and the reason behind the difference (of version with jQueryUI vs without it) is actually implementation of addClass function. With regular (plain) jQuery, the situation with addClass is as I described above, whereas with jQueryUI it is quite different. [As described here](http://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/), jQueryUI overrides addClass function and enables it to animate transition between state without and with given class name. That's why after attaching jQueryUI you get smoother animation, because you don't only animate with fadeIn/Out but also animate state by simply using `addClass` with callback.

So to sum up. If you want to get rid of jQueryUI stick to code I pasted above. If you want smoother animation, embed jQueryUI. If your concern with jQueryUI is its size, create yourself custom download and pick just a part which gives you new version of addClass function (so presumably the core will suffice).

Comment: is you look at the example you can see why i want the fade effect.

i want the list to fade out while it removed the old class and replace it with the new class then fade back in to show the new list style

http://www.psykestudios.co.uk/News%20List-Grid%20selector/

Comment: Cheers for the update, i have added it to my first preview, but its not working how i want

this is the preview im trying to create but this has the JqueryUI script attached.

http://www.psykestudios.co.uk/News%20List-Grid%20selector/index-withJqueryUI.html

Comment: It doesn't work without jQueryUI attached? If so, why? What errors do you see?

Comment: It works but not as smooth, if you look at 

http://www.psykestudios.co.uk/News%20List-Grid%20selector/index-withJqueryUI.html

that has the orginal code and has JqueryUI attached,

this is the new version without JqueryUI and the new code.

http://www.psykestudios.co.uk/News%20List-Grid%20selector/index.html

as you can see, its not as smooth, do you know how i can get this working as smooth as the JqueryUI version?